# OMAP 3530 cross compile with CodeSourcery to create a simple Linux driver

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, arm, embedded

I have finally setup successfully my OMAP 3530 to boot Embedded Linux using NFS and tftpboot. Now it is time to get into action ie. Write a simple character driver to toggle a LED on the board.
From the CodeSourcery site I have now installed arm-none-linux-gnueabi toolchain. I am having issues building a .ko file.
Usually on x86 machine I will have a makefile that looks like the following:
Makefile:

```
obj-m += hello-1.o
obj-m += hello-2.o
all:
make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(PWD) modules
clean:
make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(PWD) clean
```

What changes do I have to do in makefile (and environment variables) so that it builds a .ko file using arm-none-linux-gnueabi toolchain instead of x86 gcc? Also where do I need store and reference Linux kernel header files? 
Any examples ( makefile example) or links to resources are appreciated.

Comment: [kbuild/modules.txt](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/Documentation/kbuild/modules.txt#n146),   You need to set `$(KDIR)` to your Linux kernel build directory; and follow Rahul's advice for the compiler (also documented in KBuild (and there is menuconfig help and a KConfig option for this)).

Answer (score 1):

You have to export tool chain path and after that you need to export following environment variables

```
export CROSS_COMPILE=arm-none-linux-gnueabi-
export CC=${CROSS_COMPILE}-gcc
```

after this run make command to compile files or you can define this environment variables is makefile also.

Comment: Thanks guys. I did exactly what you suggested. I uncompressed linux source provided by OMAP 35 and pointed $KDIR to that. I dont know I am supposed to point to x86 host linux source or ARM (my guess is ARM/OMAP). Then it complained about not having .config file. so I ran make oldconfig from source directory. That created .config file. Now from my driver source (i have simple test.c and Makefile). I ran make -C $KDIR. It seemed to be using correct compiler and linux kernel source files..but I get these errors: Any clues?

Comment: In file included from arch/arm/kernel/entry-armv.S:21
arch/arm/plat-omap/include/mach/entry-macro.S:30:2: warning  "IH2 IRQ defaulted"
arch/arm/plat-omap/include/mach/entry-macro.S: Assembler messages:
arch/arm/plat-omap/include/mach/entry-macro.S:81: Error Macro `disable_fiq' was already defined
arch/arm/plat-omap/include/mach/entry-macro.S:84: Error Macro `get_irqnr_preamble' was already defined
arch/arm/plat-omap/include/mach/entry-macro.S:87: Error `arch_ret_to_user' was already defined
arch/arm/plat-omap/include/mach/entry-macro.S:91: Error `get_irqnr_and_base' was already defined

Comment: Disregard above issues. I overcame those issues by configuring linux kernel source and building it make ARCH=arm CROSS_COMPILE=${_CROSS_COMPILE} CONFIG_DEBUG_INFO=1 integrator_defconfig

Comment: However, after I create a .ko file successfully, I cannot insert the module. Insmod test.ko gives me 'invalid module format', modprobe -f gives me 'file not found'. I think the problem is vermagic (they are different). I dont know how to resolve this issue. #. modinfo gives me :filename:       test.ko
license:        GPL
alias:          test:v00000000d00000002sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
depends:
vermagic:       2.6.31-rc7-omap1 mod_unload ARMv4